Tournament of Towns Aligment of Non-Uniform Clock Hands
Tournament Of Towns,
Senior O-Level Paper, Fall 2023

There are three hands on a clock. Each of them rotates in a normal
direction at some non-zero speed, which can be wrong. In the morning
the long and the short hands coincided. Just in three hours after that
moment the long and the mid-length hands coincided. After next four
hours the short and the mid-length hands coincided. Will it
necessarily occur that all three hands will coincide?

Solution Attempt:
Call the hands $s$, $m$ and $l$ as a short form. Let $v_s, v_l, v_m$ denote their angular speeds and $\theta_l'$, $\theta_m'$, and  $\theta_s'$ denote their starting positions, and $\theta_l^t$, $\theta_m^t$, and $\theta_s^t$ denote their positions at time '$t$', calculated as $\theta_m' + v_mt$, for $m$, as an example. Then, since no information is given about the starting time, I assumed the morning to be $t=0$, and thus $\theta_s' = \theta_l'$. Also let '$t$' be time in hours.
Next, since we are on a clock, I considered $\theta$$\pmod {360}$. Then, from the question I obtained:
$$\theta_s' = \theta_l' \tag{1}$$
$$\theta_m^3 \equiv \theta_l^3 \pmod{360} \tag{2}$$
$$\theta_s^7 \equiv \theta_m^7 \pmod{360} \tag{3}$$
From (2),
$$ 360 | \theta_m' - \theta_l' + 3(v_m-v_l)$$
From (3),
$$ 360 | \theta_l' - \theta_m' + 7(v_s-v_m)$$
And thus,
$$ 360 | 7v_s - 3v_l - 4v_m $$
Or alternately,
$$ 7v_s - 3v_l \equiv 4v_m \pmod{360} \tag{4}$$
Next, assuming that the clocks coincide at a future point, the following statement holds trivially,
$$\theta_m^t \equiv \theta_l^t \equiv \theta_s^t \pmod{360} \tag{5}$$
Broken down, this yields,
$$ v_lt \equiv v_st \pmod{360} \tag{6}$$
And,
$$ v_st + \theta_l' \equiv v_mt + \theta_m'$$
But, from (3),
$$ v_st + \theta_l' - ( 7v_s + \theta_l') \equiv v_mt + \theta_m' - (7v_m + \theta_m') \pmod{360}$$
$$\implies v_s(t-7) \equiv v_m(t-7) \pmod{360} \tag{7}$$
Similarly, from (5) and (2),
$$ v_m(t-3) \equiv v_l(t-3) \pmod{360} \tag{8}$$
Adding (6),(7) and (8),
$$ (v_l + v_s + v_m)t - 3v_m - 7v_s \equiv (v_l + v_s + v_m)t - 7v_m - 3v_l \pmod{360}$$
$$ -3v_m - 7v_s \equiv -7v_m - 3v_l \pmod{360}$$
$$ 4v_m \equiv 7v_s - 3v_l \pmod{360}$$
Now, I thought, since we were able to arrive at (4), from our assumption, then our assumption is true, and thus the three hands will necessarily coincide. Is that valid? Or is that not how mathematical logic works in a proof?

No. Your argument is circular. You're saying that given $A, B, C$, we conclude $D$. Now given $E$, and looking at $E+A, E+B, E+C$, we conclude $D$. But, you didn't really use $E$ to draw that conclusion, and was just using $A, B, C$.  (Check through what you did, which was essentially a $+E - E$ situation). In order to "use" $E$, you have to find a corresponding $t$ that satisfies all equations.

Or put another way, you have $ A, B, C \Rightarrow D$ and $A, B, C, E \Rightarrrow D$. Why does this imply that $ D \Rightarrow E$? For us to draw that conclusion,  you'd need double implication errors in the second setup (which I claim we currently do not have).
